# Issue in execution of Gimp's Python-fu scripts

Tags: gimp

I followed steps in http://www.gimpusers.com/tutorials/install-python-for-gimp-2-6-windows, installing following 32-bits installers: GIMP 2.6.11, Python 2.6.6, PyGtk all-in-one.

Gimp recognized Python and PyGtk were installed in computer and now shows that option on Tools menu.

But when I tried to run this script in http://www.jamesh.id.au/software/pygimp/structure-of-plugin.html , line-by-line, I got some errors in commands below.

Any idea how to solve that?

```
    have_gimp11 = gimp.major_version > 1 or \
      gimp.major_version == 1 and gimp.minor_version >= 1

and

    main()
```

Comment: which gimp version you are using?

Comment: the version is 2.6.11

Comment: The actual error is *always* important.

Comment: yeah. I'll reproduce in my home and post later...

Comment: Migrate to [SU]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to me its related to version please check this documentation

- [GIMP Python Documentation](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html)
- [Gimp-Python from jamesh](http://www.jamesh.id.au/software/pygimp/)

Sorry if you don't find this answers useful :|

Comment: The first link appears to be more useful, since the second one points to a copy of example given in the first... I'll test in my home...